# iOS: Make a UITextField like WhatsApp Verification Code TextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

My problem is that I want to make a `UITextField` like WhatsApp verification code textField(like below image).Where default value contains number of character to be entered(as hint for user). When user enter text replace hint character with entered character one by one?

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i think this library is work for you

Comment: https://github.com/OmerCora/OCMaskedTextField

Comment: @Birendra thanks but i have to do this without using any third party library. I can't add third party library only for single textField..

Comment: so you have to do custom code for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer below link of my previous answer. Hope you will get an idea how to do this. Only single `UITextField`, No third party library use.

**link**- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769911/5097148

for don't use of **paste** make couple of changes-

add `myLable` above `textField` then add this code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
self.myLable.userInteractionEnabled=true;
UITapGestureRecognizer *LongPressgesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapPressgesture:)];
tapPressgesture.delegate=self;
[self.myLable addGestureRecognizer:tapPressgesture];
```

and

```
- (void)tapPressgesture:(UITapPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    [self.txtField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```

for background like your image you can set textField background image property or add bottom border to your textfield. `UITextField` border style must be `UITextBorderStyleNone` If you have any issue then let me know.

Happy coding:)

Comment: thanks for your help. But in your link it works fine but how can i stop pasting text into textField.

Comment: @rmk feel free to accept the any answer which solved your problem by clicking right tick.. Happy to help you:)

Answer (score 0):

After adding 6 Textfields and background image.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    return YES;
}


-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    if (textField==textfield1)
    {

        [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];


    }

    else if (textField==textfield2)
    {
        [textfield2 resignFirstResponder];
        [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];


    }


}
```

continue till textfield 6

Comment: got any doubt ask me

Comment: @rmk still facing issue..?